# Ionic disable swipe on right menu but not on left menu

Tags: menu, swipe, ionic-framework, swipe-gesture

In my Ionic app I have two menus, left and right. I want to deactivate the "swipe to open menu" on the right menu, but not on the left.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```html
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ion-side-menus>
        <!-- Left menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item href="#/detail"><i class="icon ion-heart"></i>&nbsp; Rate App</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/detail"><i class="icon ion-share"></i>&nbsp; Share App</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/detail"><i class="icon ion-more"></i>&nbsp; More Apps</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/detail"><i class="icon ion-android-mail"></i>&nbsp; Contact</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu>

        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                <button class="button button-icon" menu-toggle="left">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
                <button class="button button-dark" menu-toggle="right">
                    <i class="ion-android-download"></i> Download App
                </button>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <!-- Main content -->
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>          

        <!-- Right menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="right">
            <ion-pane class="right">
                <p>Some content in the right menu</p>
            </ion-pane>
        </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm having same trouble. Did you found a solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

It's not a proper solution, but it fixes this a little :) It will return the content back to the origin position. For the other side use 275 instead of -275 in compared css matrix value.

```
$rootScope.$watch(function(){
    return $("ion-side-menu-content").css("transform");
}, function(css) {
    if(css == "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -275, 0)") {
        $("ion-side-menu-content").css("transform", "translate3d(0px 0px 0px)");
        $("ion-side-menu-content").css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0px 0px 0px)");
        $("ion-side-menu-content").css("-ms-transform", "translate3d(0px 0px 0px)");
    }
});
```